# Clean copy of HTML code and save as a separate HTML file

Tags: javascript

I have got an HTML page with "export" button. The task is by clicking on the "export HTML" button - copy code of the whole page, remove some elements and then save this code as a separate HTML file. I am using the JavaScript below but it modifies DOM in the browser which shouldn't do.

```
function exportHTML() {
    clean();
    var content = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
    download(content, "index", "html");
}

function clean() {
    var contentToDelete = document.querySelectorAll(".clean");
    var editableContent = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable=true]");
    for (var i = 0; i < editableContent.length; i++) {
      editableContent[i].removeAttribute('contenteditable');
    }
    contentToDelete.forEach((element) => element.remove());
}

function download(content, fileName, fileType) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    var file = new Blob([content], {
      type: "html"
    });
    var downloadFile = fileName + "." + fileType;
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    link.download = downloadFile;
    link.click();
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Removing elements modifies the DOM; what do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Hi @kellys, I meant copy the code of the page, clean it by removing elements - clean() function and save a separate HTML file. Hope it makes sense. At the moment clean() function just removes elements from the page/DOM and saves it as a separate file.

Comment: Hi @canon thank you, I will have a look at DOMParser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a really good advice from @canon I have managed to make it working with the following code:

```
function exportHTML() {
    var strHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(strHTML, "text/html");
    var contentToDelete = doc.querySelectorAll(".clean");
    var editableContent = doc.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable=true]");
    for (var i = 0; i < editableContent.length; i++) {
      editableContent[i].removeAttribute('contenteditable');
    }
    contentToDelete.forEach((element) => element.remove());

    var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    var outHTML = serializer.serializeToString(doc);

    var content = outHTML;
    download(content, "index", "html");
};
```

Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 1):

You're cleaning the code out first, which in your comments, you said you want it to "copy" first. Instead of `clean()` first, just copy/store it first and retry.

instead do this:

```js
function exportHTML() {
    var content = document.documentElement.innerHTML; // 1st get the original
    clean(); // 2nd
    download(content, "index", "HTML"); // 3rd
}
```

It might also be better to store the content outside the function to ensure it's not changed inside the scope of another function.

```js
const content = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

```js
function exportHTML() {
    clean(); // 2nd
    download(content, "index", "HTML"); // 3rd
}
```